# Knokout select : Set Selected Item by item name not value

Tags: jquery, select, knockout.js

i have a knockout select as following

**observable Array**

*issuingCountries*

```
    0: 
       ObjectCoordinatorRegion: "EU"
       Country: "Australia"
       CountryId: 14
       Id: 1
   2: 
       ObjectCoordinatorRegion: "AU"
       Country: "Japan"
       CountryId: 16
       Id: 2
```

**html**

```
<select class="issuing_country" data-bind="options: issuingCountries,
                                           optionsText : 'Country',                               
                                           value:IssuingcountrySelected,
                                           optionsCaption:'---Select---',
                                         "
                        >
                        </select>
```

My question , i have  { Country: "Japan" } in my hand,so how to set particular selected item as selected in dropdown.?
so far i have tried

```
$('.issuing_country option[text="Japan"]').prop('selected', true);
```

but failed ,let me know anyother way to do this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to set anything like that using jQuery when using knockout - instead, do it all on the viewmodel.

Your `<select>` options are bound to your `issuingCountries` `observableArray`, and the value selected is bound to your `IssuingcountrySelected` `observable`.  To select an option automatically, just set the property on your viewmodel, and knockout will take care of the rest:

```
//Assuming "Japan" is at index 2:
vm.IssuingcountrySelected(vm.issuingCountries()[2]);
```

If all you know is the name of the option you want to select, first you must find the right item, so you'd need a function for that:

```
function findCountryByName(name) {
    for (var x = 0; x < vm.issuingCountries().length; x++) {
        if (vm.issuingCountries()[x].Country == name)
            return vm.issuingCountries()[x];
    }
    return null;
}
vm.IssuingcountrySelected(findCountryByName("Japan"));
```

Comment: is it possible to do a generic code..? assume i have many slect box like this, so i need to set all values. so is it possible to do a generic findCountryByName.?

Comment: Yes, you could write a function that takes the observable you want to set, the array to search, the name of the property to look in and the value of the property you want to find.  If you have problems implementing such a function, I'd recommend a new question here on StackOverflow as that's a bit different to your original question on this page.

Comment: i can only post one question in 90 minut. can you please add your code here, i wil add question later and let you know.

Comment: 90 minutes sounds like a reasonable amount of time to try to research and implement a function yourself first :)

Comment: self.getOptionByName = function(instance,opt,name){
            console.log(instance()[x]+'."'+opt+'"');
            for (var x = 0; x < instance().length; x++) {
                console.log(instance()[x].opt);
                if (instance()[x].opt == name)
                    return instance()[x];
                }
            return null;
        }

Comment: here is the question link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843510/general-function-for-observable-array-search