# General function for observable array search

Tags: knockout.js

is there a way to do a general function for search an observable array and if the value found then set that object to another observable .?
this question relate to 
[Knokout select : Set Selected Item by item name not value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841660/knokout-select-set-selected-item-by-item-name-not-value/30842138#30842138)

so far i have tried

```
self.getOptionByName = function(instance,opt,name){
            console.log(instance()[x]+'."'+opt+'"');
            for (var x = 0; x < instance().length; x++) {
                console.log(instance()[x].opt);
                if (instance()[x].opt == name)
                    return instance()[x];
                }
            return null;
        }
```

and called as

```
self.IssuingcountrySelected(self.popup.getOptionByName(self.issuingCountries,'Country','Japan'))
```

and my observable array is

```
0: 
       ObjectCoordinatorRegion: "EU"
       Country: "Australia"
       CountryId: 14
       Id: 1
   2: 
       ObjectCoordinatorRegion: "AU"
       Country: "Japan"
       CountryId: 16
       Id: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.IssuingcountrySelected = ko.observable();
    self.issuingCountries = ko.observableArray(json);

    var getOptionByName = function (instance, opt, name) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(instance, function (item) { //returns first matched record
            if (item[opt] == name) {
                return item[opt];
            }
        });
    }

    self.IssuingcountrySelected(getOptionByName(self.issuingCountries(), 'Country', 'Japan'))
    //You get the matched object else null
    console.log(self.IssuingcountrySelected()) // check console 
};
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24676/)**

Answer (score 0):

i got another way, let me know if the following code is standard way or not

```
self.findOptionByName = function(instance,opt,name){            
            for (var x = 0; x < instance().length; x++) {
                var curObj = instance()[x];
                if ( curObj.hasOwnProperty(opt) && curObj[opt] === name){
                    return instance()[x];
                }
           }
           return null;
        }
```

then call as

```
 self.IssuingcountrySelected(self.findOptionByName(self.issuingCountries,'Country',country));
```